# Multiple Listeners for different queues - Spring Rabbit

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have multiple modules which communicate each other by mean of a message queue (Spring Rabbit). Some modules produce messages and others consume them. However, a single module can listen different queues, I have a list of queue names in a list, so I created a  `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` for each queue name as follow.

```
public void build() {
    for (String queueName: queues) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerContainer.setQueueNames(queueName);
        listenerContainer.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter());
    }
}

@Bean
private MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            System.out.println(message.getBody());
        }
    }, "onMessage");
}
```

This implementation is not working for me, consumer are not registered in the queue and any error or exception is throwing during execution.

Note: I am using Spring and I am limited to not use annotations such as  `@RabbitListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` manually, not as beans, you have also to ensure application context callbacks and lifecycle:

```
listenerContainer.setApplicationContext()
listenerContainer.setApplicationEventPublisher()
listenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet()
listenerContainer.start()
```

And don't forget to `stop()` and `destroy()` them in the end of application.

Comment: is it possible to create beans dynamically? a bean factory?

Comment: Right, but that's not so easy. See `DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerSingleton()` and `initializeBean()`. Although you can take a look into the `GenericApplicationContext.registerBean(@Nullable String beanName, Class<T> beanClass, @Nullable Supplier<T> supplier,
   BeanDefinitionCustomizer... customizers)`